# What is the category I should choose for my Android App?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a app called PlayText which lets you to listen to the text from websites as audio.(It's some kind of voice browser)

I have choosen the category as Productivity..Whether that is the right category for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say Apps > Productivity is a good selection.

Comment: The app is very close to the functionality of  a browser.. I see opera browser is listed under communication whether I should change to communications category?